# Body 100% height is sligtly more then 100 vh on Phongap application

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, phonegap

Hi i am making a PhonaGap application. Main scene contains only cnavas that has 100% width and 100% height. That works fine but my body sligtly overlaping bottom corner so if user scroll lit a bit whole screen moves down.

This is how canvas looks like. You can see it has 100% 100% size.
[image: demo 1]

After scroll down whole scene moves like 5px down. And you can see that body has more height then 100%
[image: Demo 2]

Here is my styles for canvas and body. No other elements are on this scene.

```
cnavas{
  width: 100%; /* alredy tried 100vw ,100vh and same result */
  heigth: 100%;
}
body{
  padding: 0; /* alredy tried set body to 100% ,100% and same result */
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
```

}

I can't do overflow:hidden cause in other scenes i need screen to be scrollable.
Also in future canvas will be scrolable as well and have more then 100% height. My goal is hide that body part of screen so there will be no space under canvas.

Comment: display:block to canvas

Comment: Wow now its working thank you man. It was a lot of easier then i tought it would be.